# Configuring SR830 driver functions in LabVIEW block diagram

Tags: function, labview, measurement

I want to plot measurement values from an SR830 lock-in Amp as function of discreet voltage values using LabVIEW for a magneto optic Kerr effect (MOKE) experimenter. However, I couldn't find any doc explaining the properties/attributes of the SR830 driver function VIs.

I've downloaded the SR830 driver recommended by NI from (http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=1536) and stored it in `LabVIEW/instr.lib dir`. I also connected my lock-in Amp to my computer using GPIB-USB and configured it with the "Measurement & Automation Explorer" but I just don't know how to actually use the SR830 function VIs.

Comment: Have you tried visiting the instrument control discussion forum linked on the drivers page? https://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/bd-p/140?profile.language=en

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out, how to program your device, check example VIs.
Goto `Help` -> `Find Examples...` -> navigate in `Browse` tab to `Hardware Input and Output` -> `Instruments Drivers` -> `LabVIEW Plug and Play`, and check VIs examples for "Stanford Research" drivers.
Or, in `Find Examples` window click on `Search` tab, and search for "Stanford" keyword.